# What's with the definite article in "It was in the bleak December"?

Tags: definite-articles, poetry

In his classic poem which pretty much everyone knows by heart, Edgar Allan Poe writes as follows:

> Ah, distinctly I remember
> It was **in the bleak December**,
> And each separate dying ember
> Wrought its ghost upon the floor.

Why?

"... **a** bleak December" would have sounded (or would it?) more logical: not all Decembers are bleak.

Or:

"This occurred in bleak December" would have scanned just as well.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an idiosyncrasy of Poe to use a definite article when there's an adjective preceding the month:

*[The Island of the Fay](https://www.eapoe.org/works/tales/islfayc.htm)*:

> I came upon them suddenly in **the leafy June**, and threw myself upon the turf, beneath the branches of an unknown odorous shrub, that I might doze as I contemplated the scene.

*[To -- -- --. Ulalume: A Ballad](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44889/to-ulalume-a-ballad)*

> The skies they were ashen and sober;
> The leaves they were crispéd and sere—
> The leaves they were withering and sere;
> It was night in **the lonesome October**
> Of my most immemorial year;

In [The Bridge of Sighs](https://englishverse.com/poems/the_bridge_of_sighs), there's no article, presumably because there's no adjective.

> The bleak wind of March
> Made her tremble and shiver;

I don't *think* there's any explanation beyond that, given that I've not seen this used elsewhere. (Edit: Now I have seen [some examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20bleak%20december%22&tbm=bks&ei=JbOLZMSMGo6jptQPmf6T4A0&ved=0ahUKEwiEs7eyysb_AhWOkYkEHRn_BNwQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22the%20bleak%20december%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAMyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwI6BwghEKsCEAo6BAghEApQhCFY_ydgzCtoAHAAeACAAc8BiAH_BpIBBTEuNS4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books&safe=active&ssui=on), and I can't think of an explanation for why.)

Comment: Surely not a question of style?  "Now is the winter of our discontent" kind of stands out, too.  It's just...definite.

Comment: @livresque: How does it stand out? It's not just any old winter, it's a very specific winter: the winter of our discontent.

Comment: It's just another well known line.  At least a little more optimistic.  Yes, definite articles tend to be used for something specific.  I do wish I understood the anomaly you're asking for.